# Program in 8086 assembly language to compare two numbers

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, x86-16

The following is my code in assembly language to compare two numbers and print a test character to confirm if it's written correctly.

```
DATA SEGMENT

    NUM1 DB 50
    NUM2 DB 45
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT

    ASSUME CS: CODE, DS: DATA
START: MOV AX, DATA

    MOV DS, AX
    MOV AL, NUM1
    MOV BL, NUM2
    CMP AL, BL
    JLE TAG
    TAG: MOV DL, AL
         MOV AH, 02H
         MOV DL,  'T'
         INT 21H
    MOV AX, 4CH
    INT 21H
    CODE ENDS
    END START
```

My assumption is, CMP will compare AL to BL. If AL is smaller, JLE will be true and the code in the part 'TAG' will be executed. As you can see AL is not smaller, still, TAG is executed.

Comment: Is JLE jump if unsigned smaller or signed smaller?  And is there a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure. I realized one thing is that maybe in this language...it goes to TAG regardless of whether the condition is met. Perhaps a JMP is required to make sure TAG is executed only when it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

In assembly language. It goes top-down and will come across the code in the TAG section regardless of the condition being met or not. Simply adding a JMP command (before the TAG section begins) will make it go to termination directly after checking the condition to ensure it gives a logically correct answer.

Comment: Or even simpler invert the condition and skip the TAG block.

Comment: Yes, keep in mind the CPU does execute next instruction from address in `CS:PC` registers. They are like ordinary registers, just holding some 16:16 bit values, and `PC` is special in the way how CPU does increment it after instruction decoding and `mov pc,value` is done by `jmp`, not by `mov`, etc... but they are just registers in the end. So to control execution path, you must adjust `PC` value. `Jcc` will adjust `PC` with value from argument, when condition is met, otherwise the `PC` is left without change (it is already pointing to next instruction during `Jcc` execution).

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is, CMP will compare AL to BL. If AL is **smaller**, JLE will be true and the code in the part 'TAG' will be executed. As you can see AL is not **smaller**, still, TAG is executed.

I was a bit worried when I read this. I hope you know that the `JLE` mnemonic stands for **jump if less OR EQUAL**. If you only need to decide about smaller (and this seems to be the case) then you would better use the `jl` instruction (jump if less).

---

The real problem then with your code (and you already solved this yourself) is that with a construct like:

```
    jcc label
label:
    ...
```

the code at *label* is always executed because

- if the condition is true the execution **jumps** to the code at *label*
- if the condition is false the execution **falls thru** in the code at *label*

A simple way to solve this would be to insert an unconditional jump right before the *label*, so that in the event the condition wasn't true the code at *label* could be jumped over:

```
    cmp al, bl
    jl  label
    jmp beyond
label:
    mov ah, 02h    ;Executed only is AL is smaller than BL
    mov dl, 'T'
    int 21h
beyond: 
    ...
```

An even simpler way to solve this issue is to just bypass the code at *label* by using the opposite conditional jump. There's also no longer need for the *label* itself.

For `jl` the opposite conditional jump is `jge` (jump if greater or equal)
For `jle` the opposite conditional jump is `jg` (jump if greater)

```
    cmp al, bl
    jge beyond
    mov ah, 02h    ;Executed only is AL is smaller than BL
    mov dl, 'T'
    int 21h
beyond:
    ...
```

---

### A note on the numbers involved.

If you treat the numbers as **signed** quantities, then using `jl` (jump if less) and `jg` (jump if greater) is the correct way.
On the other hand if the numbers are to be treated as **unsigned** quantities you need to use the `jb` (jump if below) and `ja` (jump if above) instructions.